# Bounding the number of commutative rings with identity of size n

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

For integer $n \geq 2$, the number of rngs of size $n$ is in general an open problem.

Let $a(n)$ be the number of commutative rngs of size $n$.
We can use the facts that $a(n)$ is multiplicative
and that $a(p^n) = p^{2/27 * n^3 + O(n^{8/3})}$, for prime $p$,
to estimate $a(n)$ for general $n$.
These rings do not necessarily have identity.
https://oeis.org/A037289

Let $b(n)$ be the number of rings with identity of size $n$.
These rings are not necessarily commutative.
A few terms of this sequence are known:
https://oeis.org/A037291

Let $c(n)$ be the number of commutative rings with identity.
We know commutative rings with identity are direct products of local rings
(rings with a unique maximal ideal),
so if we knew the number of local rings of a given (prime-power) size,
we could find $c(n)$.

We know $c(n) \leq a(n)$ and $c(n) \leq b(n)$,
and some crude lower bounds on $c(n)$ 
can be found by considering classes of rings of size $n$,
such as direct sums of integer rings.

I know all of the local rings of size $p^n$ are known for $n=1,2,3,4,5$,
but are there bounds on the number of commutative rings of size $n$
or the number of local rings of size $p^n$ for general $n$?

Comment: [This answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/7140/39640) might be of interest.